# React js google api suggestion AutocompleteService getPlacePredictions restriction to a specific state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have the following component, which you suggest me an address.

The problem is that I need the addresses you suggest to me to refer to a single state.

Is there a way to specify this restriction via API?

Or is there a way that I could do via code in your opinion?

I thought I was doing something inside, do you want it to think it's a correct way?
Could I have problems?

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;
    if (!autocompleteService.current && window.google)
        autocompleteService.current = new window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    if (!autocompleteService.current) return undefined;
    if (value === '') {
        setOptions([]);
        return undefined;
    }
    fetch({ input: value }, res => {

        //edit
        const loc = res.map(a => (a.description.split(',').pop().trim() === 'Italia' ? a : false)).filter(Boolean);

        if (active) setOptions(loc || []);
    });
    return () => {
        active = false;
    };
}, [value, fetch]);
```

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { makeStyles, TextField, Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Autocomplete } from '@material-ui/lab';
import { LocationOn } from '@material-ui/icons';
import parse from 'autosuggest-highlight/parse';
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';

function loadScript(src, position, id) {
    if (!position) return;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('async', '');
    script.setAttribute('id', id);
    script.src = src;
    position.appendChild(script);
}
const autocompleteService = { current: null };
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    icon: {
        color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
    }
}));

export default function AutocompleteGoogleMaps(props) {
    const { api, value, onChange, changeinfo } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
    const loaded = React.useRef(false);

    const { i18n } = useTranslation();
    let language = localStorage.getItem('lang');
    if (language === null) language = i18n.language;

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !loaded.current) {
        if (!document.querySelector('#google-maps')) {
            loadScript(
                `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${api}&libraries=places&language=${language}`,
                document.querySelector('head'),
                'google-maps'
            );
        }
        loaded.current = true;
    }

    const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
        onChange(value);
    };

    const onTagsChange = (event, val) => {
        if (val !== null && val.description !== null) {
            onChange({ target: { value: val.description } });
            if (changeinfo) geocodeByAddress(val.description).then(changeinfo);
        }
    };

    const fetch = React.useMemo(
        () =>
            throttle((input, callback) => {
                autocompleteService.current.getPlacePredictions(input, callback);
            }, 200),
        []
    );

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let active = true;
        if (!autocompleteService.current && window.google)
            autocompleteService.current = new window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        if (!autocompleteService.current) return undefined;
        if (value === '') {
            setOptions([]);
            return undefined;
        }
        fetch({ input: value }, res => {
            if (active) setOptions(res || []);
        });
        return () => {
            active = false;
        };
    }, [value, fetch]);

    const geocodeByAddress = address => {
        const geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
        const { OK } = window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            geocoder.geocode({ address }, (results, status) => {
                if (status !== OK) {
                    return reject(status);
                }
                return resolve(results);
            });
        });
    };

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            id="google-map"
            getOptionLabel={option => (typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.description)}
            filterOptions={x => x}
            options={options}
            autoComplete
            includeInputInList
            freeSolo
            value={value}
            renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} onChange={handleChange} {...props} />}
            onChange={onTagsChange}
            renderOption={({
                structured_formatting: {
                    main_text_matched_substrings: matches,
                    main_text: city,
                    secondary_text: street
                }
            }) => {
                const parts = parse(
                    city,
                    matches.map(match => [match.offset, match.offset + match.length])
                );
                return (
                    <Grid container alignItems="center">
                        <Grid item>
                            <LocationOn className={classes.icon} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs>
                            {parts.map(({ highlight, text }, key) => (
                                <span key={key} style={{ fontWeight: highlight ? 700 : 400 }}>
                                    {text}
                                </span>
                            ))}
                            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                                {street}
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                );
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar entry for this feature request in the Google Issue Tracker so that we can provide information on it to all Google Maps Platform APIs users, as the technical aspects of this issue are of interest to a number of our customers,

Issues and Feature Requests in the Issue Tracker are directly curated by Places API specialists, who will provide updates in the Issue Tracker whenever there's news from the engineering team.

We would like to warmly invite you to view the issue in the Issue Tracker, and to star it to register your interest. This will subscribe you to receive technical updates on the issue. Starring the issue also provides us with valuable feedback on the importance of the issue to our customers, and increases the issue's priority with the product engineering team.

You can view and star the issue here:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/35822067

This Issue Tracker entry is the authoritative source for public information regarding this issue, and all publicly-relevant updates will be posted there.

Comment: In the end a stratagem seems to have managed to solve the problem.